# Why is antlr4 c grammar parser rule "typeSpecifier" not using lexer rule "Double"?

Tags: antlr4

I am using the [antlr4 c grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4) as inspiration for my own grammar. I came over one thing I dont really get. Why is there Lexer rules for datatypes when they are not used? For example the rule `Double : 'double';` is never used but the parser rule `typeSpecifier:('double' | ... );`(other datatypes has been removed to simplify) is used several places. Is there a reason why the parser rule **typeSpecifier** is not using the lexer rule **Double**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the grammars on that page are volunteer submissions and not part of ANTLR4.  It's clearly a mistake, but the way lexer rules are matched, it won't make a difference in lexing.  You can choose to implement either the explicit rule:

```
Double : 'double';
```

or the implicit one:

```
typeSpecifier
    :   ('void'
    |   'char'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   'long'
    |   'float'
    |   'double'
```

with no ill effects either way, even if you mix methods.  In fact, if you take a more global look at that whole grammar, the author did the same thing with numerous other lexer rules, like `Register` for example.  Makes no difference in actual practice.

Bottom line?  Choose whichever method you like and apply it consistently.  My personal preference is toward brevity, so I like the the implicit tokens **so long as they are used in only one place in the grammar**.  As soon as a token might be used in two places, I prefer to make an explicit token out of it and update the two or more locations where it's used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!